# How to update a bool using setState in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to create a login app using Flutter and I have a problem trying to update a bool. Let me give a description about my problem. If you have any advice or feedback, please let me know.

problem: _buttonLogin() is in charge of catching and checking user's username and password.For this I'm using the following methods: **_movePage()** and **_checkWebsiteResponse()** that are located in the **_LoginPageState** Class, and **userExists()** that is located in the **CheckLogin** class. The problem here is that my **_websiteResponse** variable is not beign updated  when I call **_checkWebsiteResponse()**. Let me give you a little description for each method.

**_movePage():** Method in charge to do Navegation if the websiteResponse is true.
**_checkWebsiteResponse():** Method in charge to update _websiteResponse variable by calling userExists() method.
**_userExists():** Method in charge to save the websiteResponse in case where the user and pin matches with the webiste url.

```
Widget _buttonLogin(){
    return StreamBuilder(
        builder: (BuildContext context,AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
          return ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: _movePage,
            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
              primary: Colors.orange,
              onSurface: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
              ),
              elevation: 10.0,
            ),
              child: Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 80.0,vertical: 15.0),
                child: const Text("Log In"),
              ),
          );
        }
    );
  }

  void _movePage(){
    checkLogin.username = _emailController.text;
    checkLogin.password = _passwordController.text;
    _checkWebsiteResponse;
    setState(() {
      if(checkLogin.websiteResponse == true){
        //_message = "email:$_email\npassword:$_password";
        Navigator.of(context).push(
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder:(context)=>const MyBitcoinAppPage(title: 'Bitcoin App'),
          ),
        );
      }else{
        _message = "Wrong Email/Password.\n${checkLogin.username}"
            "\n${checkLogin.password}\n${checkLogin.websiteResponse}";
      }
    });
  }
  void _checkWebsiteResponse(){
    checkLogin.userExists().then((value) => setState((){}));
  }

class CheckLogin{

  ///Variables
  var _username = '';
  var _password = '';
  bool _websiteResponse = false;

  ///Getters and Setters
  get username => _username;

  set username(value) {
    _username = value;
  }

  get password => _password;

  set password(value) {
    _password = value;
  }

  bool get websiteResponse => _websiteResponse;

  set websiteResponse(bool value) {
    _websiteResponse = value;
  }

  Future<void> userExists() async {
    var usernameInput = username;
    var passwordInput = password;

    var url = Uri.https(
        'www.cs.utep.edu', '/cheon/cs4381/homework/quiz/login.php',
        {'user':usernameInput,'pin':passwordInput});
    var response = await http.get(url);
    var httpBody = response.body;
    var decoded = json.decode(httpBody);

    _websiteResponse = decoded['response'];
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the json coming back from the server?

Comment: Yes, I did a small example in other dart file and the websiteResponse changes to true at the end.

Comment: Where's the stream for your streambuilder?